# how to generate ethereum address from mnemonic and derivation path without using ethereumjs-wallet npm package?

Tags: ethereumjs, bip39

**Is there any way to generate ethereum address from mnemonic and derivation path without using  ethereumjs-wallet npm package?**

I have generated mnemonic using bip39 
and i can generate Ethereum address using ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey package  for any derivation path but i want any other way
I don't want to use ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey

Comment: Why you do not want to use ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey? It should be possible but you will be implementing a lot of functionality from that package. Underneat ethereumjs-wallet uses [hdkey](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/hdkey) package.

Comment: Actually i have to ethereum address using derivation path in flutter, but problem is that there is no library like ethereumjs-wallet in flutter

Comment: The algorithm is described in the [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki). You will need some crypto primitives like HMAC SHA512 or implement them yourself.